# Collab terminates itself ^c before finishing render

Tags: python, linux, blender

**My code terminates itself on Blender when itself on Blender in the middle of rendering.
Here is the code: It works on other blend files but not this one (so I doubt the code is the problem**

```
#Connect Google Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/drive/')

#Set Paths to Blender Files
filename = '/drive/MyDrive/blender-3.1.2-linux-x64.tar.xz'

#Unzip Blender (Only need to do once)
```

!tar xf '//drive/MyDrive/blender-3.1.2-linux-x64.tar.xz'

```
#Set Paths to Blender Files
filename = '/drive/MyDrive/Renders/realisticbeachwavesaleft1.blend'

!chmod +x /content/blender-3.1.2-linux-x64/blender

#Deletes the Default libtcmalloc-minimal4 version and installs the Ubuntu default version
import os

os.environ["LD_PRELOAD"] = ""

#Deletes wrong Version of libtcmalloc-minimal4
!apt remove libtcmalloc-minimal4
#Installs correct version of libtcmalloc-minimal4
!apt install libtcmalloc-minimal4

#Adds this library to the user environment
os.environ["LD_PRELOAD"] = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4.3.0"

!/content/blender-3.1.2-linux-x64/blender -b $filename -noaudio -E 'CYCLES' -o 
'/drive/MyDrive/Renders/image_####' -s 0 -e 01 -a -- --cycles-device CUDA
```

**Then This is the result I get:**
Bunch of codes then...

```
Fra:0 Mem:3850.91M (Peak 3882.92M) | Time:00:29.42 | Mem:111.42M, Peak:111.42M | Scene, 
ViewLayer | Updating Images | Loading lakeside_16k.exr
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked when I rendered with a file instead:

```
!blender -b -noaudio --python /content/code/render.py -E CYCLES -a --cycles-device CUDA
```

The code had:

```
import bpy  
bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport=True)
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```